# create an array of names from a file

Tags: arrays, bash

I would like to create an array using bash commands of names. I have a file with this form,

```
<span class="username js-action-profile-name">@paulburt07</span>
<span class="username js-action-profile-name">@DavidWBrown7</span>
<span class="username js-action-profile-name">@MikeLarkan</span>
<span class="username js-action-profile-name">@WeathermanABC</span>
<span class="username js-action-profile-name">@JoshHoltTEN</span>
<span class="username js-action-profile-name">@TonyAuden</span>
<span class="username js-action-profile-name">@Magdalena_Roze</span>
<span class="username js-action-profile-name">@janesweather7</span>
<span class="username js-action-profile-name">@VanessaOHanlon</span>
```

And I need an array like

```
array = ( "paulburt07" "DavidWBrown7" "MikeLarkan" "WeathermanABC" "JoshHolTEN" "TonyAuden" "Magdalena_Roze" "janesweahter7" "VansessaOHanlon" )
```

Any idea?

Comment: I missed them, now they are

Answer (score 2):

One of many possible solutions:

```
array=($(grep -oP '@\K(.*)(?=<)' file))
```

**EDIT:**
Not much to explanation, the `grep` searches the file for the pattern defined by the regular expression. (see `man grep`). The `-o` prints only the matches, the `-P` says, use *perl-ish* regexes.

The `@\K(.*)(?=<)` mean:

- search and match `@`
- forget the match `\K`, (but remember the position)
- match ant string `(.*)`
- until found `<`

the `$(command)` called as command substitution, and `array=(...)` assingns the values to the array.

**EDIT2**
And because you original input probably contains more HTML tags, you can employ HTML parser, for example:

```
array=($(perl -Mojo -E 'say $_->text for x(b("filename.html")->slurp)->find(q{span[class~="username"]})->each'))
```

will print the content of any `<span class=username>...</span>` in any HTML, regardless it's formatting. But for the above you need to have installed [Mojolicious](https://metacpan.org/pod/ojo).

Comment: when I type echo $array I only receive the first name paulburt07

Comment: This is the normal behaviour, @EnricAgudPique . To loop through the contents you need to say `for item in "${array[@]}"; do echo "$item"; done`.

Comment: Oh yes! Sorry for me question

Comment: Could you explain me your command? array=($(grep -oP '@\K(.*)(?=<)' file)) thank you

Comment: It is a very elegant use of grep with `-o` keep only matching parts of the line, along with `-P` (use Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) which essentially kills everything up to the first `@` and keeps everything before the next `<`. I would have to refer to a PCRE reference for exact terminology.

Answer (score 1):

It is fairly simple using `sed` and a tmp file:

```
#!/bin/bash

fname=${1:-htmlnames.txt}           # original html file
tmp=${2:-htmltmp.txt}               # temp file to use

sed -e 's/.*@//' "$fname" > "$tmp"  # remove up to '@' and place in temp
sed -i 's/[<].*$//' "$tmp"          # remove remainder in place in temp
namearray=( $(<"$tmp") )            # read temp file into array
rm "$tmp"                           # remove temp file

for i in "${namearray[@]}"; do        # print out to verify
    printf " %s\n" "$i"
done

exit 0
```

**output:**

```
alchemy:~/scr/tmp/stack/tmp> bash htmlnames.sh
 paulburt07
 DavidWBrown7
 MikeLarkan
 WeathermanABC
 JoshHoltTEN
 TonyAuden
 Magdalena_Roze
 janesweather7
 VanessaOHanlon
```

Comment: better to quote `${namearray[@]}` so that names with spaces will be handled properly.